# Parsing SNMP results in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, snmp, cisco

I am looking for a collecter information by SNMP on Cisco router.
I collect the information without any problem. The problem is in my Perl regex.

Received by the array here SNMP:

```
$ mystring = 'iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.2 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet1/2"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.3 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/1"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.4 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/2"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.5 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/3"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.6 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/4"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.7 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/5"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.8 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/6"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.9 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/7"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.10 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/8"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.11 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/9"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.12 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/10"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.13 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/11"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.14 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/12"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.15 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/13"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.16 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/14"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.17 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/15"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.18 = STRING: "GigabitEthernet3/16" ';
@ array = ($ mystring = ~ m /. ([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]) = / gms);
print join ("\ n", @ array);
```

I have the latest issue of the mib but how to get the port? for example

```
array(    
5->GigabitEthernet3/3
6->GigabitEthernet3/4
);
```

in a table.

Comment: Why not use the existing [Net::SNMP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SNMP/) module rather than rolling your own?

Comment: @Giveme Please note that the *sigils* `$@%` are part of variable names and are not *exactly* operators, so it might be better to remove the additional space.  Also, the `=~` (regex binding) is different from `=` assignment and `~` negation. Your `/m` option is cargo cult programming and carries no meaning here, while `/s` changes the meaning of `.` to "match anything, including newlines". To match a period character `.`, it has to be escaped, like `\.`. The `->` operator does method invocation. `array()` is a PHPism; to use it, write `sub array {wantarray ? @_ : \@_}` in your code ;)

Comment: Thank you for the information, I am in the middle of PHP. I still have some gaps in perl;)

Answer (score 2):

What you call array is actually an associative array. A hash table is a form of associative array.

```
use strict; use warnings;
my %port_by_mib;
for (split /\n/, $mystring) {
    my ($mib) = /\.(\d+) / or die;
    my ($port) = /"([^"]+)"/ or die;
    $port_by_mib{$mib} = $port;
}
```

#### Explanation:

- `use strict` runs Perl in a stricter mode. This disallows dangerous or error-prone features. `use warnings` will issue warnings that help debugging a script.
- The `my` keyword declares lexical variables. Declaring your variables is required in strict mode. If you forgot to declare a name, you will get a `global symbol "$foo" requires explicit package name ...` fatal error.
- The `%` is the sigil for hash tables. Sigils are both a type declaration and a namespace selector.
- `split` cuts `$mystring` whenever the regex matches. `for` loops over the resulting list of substrings and assigns each piece to the `$_` default argument.
- The regex `/\.(\d+) /` matches and saves any sequence of digits that is preceded by a dot and followed by a space. The script `die`s (i.e throws a fatal error) when no such match is found. The left hand side of the assignment has a list context, so the RHS is executed in list context as well, causing `$mib` to be initialized with the first capture buffer.
- The regex `/"([^"]+)"/` matches text in double-quotes, and extracts that text.
- Hash tables are accessed with curly braces, not with square brackets as with arrays.

Comment: I included strict and warnings and added a somewhat lengthy explanation of the code.

Comment: for (split /\n/, $mystring) {
    my ($mib)   = /\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]) / or die;
    my ($port)  = m/(\"(.*)")/s or die;
    push @{$mib}, $port;
}

print Dumper \@$mib;

exit;

Comment: huh, I didn't use `push`?!?!

Comment: our modification, sorry i use push just for learning : for (split /\n/, $mystring) { my ($mib) = /\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]) / or die; my ($port) = m/(\"(.*)")/s or die; push @{$mib}, $port; } print Dumper \@$mib; exit;

Comment: @Giveme The `@{$mib}` tries to treat `$mib` as an array reference. At it is a string, it doesn't work. `push` only operates on arrays, and is of no use here. Also, ikegamis regexes are better, and for `$port` you probably meant the better `/"([^"]+)"/`,without `/s` or escapes, but with a character class.

Comment: `push` takes an array argument, but as I said in my answer, you showed you wanted a hash. `push` doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Ok, my result good for me. my %port_by_mib;
my $key;
my $value;

for (split /\n/, $mystring) {
#    my ($mib)  = /\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]) = / or die;
    my ($mib) = /\.(\d+) / or die;
    my ($port)  = /"([^"]+)"/ or die;
    $port_by_mib{$mib} = $port;
}

while (($key,$value) = each %port_by_mib) {
        $value =~ s/\//-/g;
        print "$key=$value\n";
}



exit;

Comment: @Giveme Why, that looks good! Although minor nitpicks would lead to `my %port_by_mib; for(...){...} while( my($key,$value) = each %port_by_mib ){ $value =~ tr!/!-!; say "$key=$value"; }` sans `exit`, and assuming `use feature 'say'`. Actually, to receive a sorted output, you would use a `for`-loop again: `for my $key ( sort {$a <=> $b} keys %port_by_mib ){ (my $val = $port_by_mib{$key}) =~ tr!/!-!; say "$key=$val"; }`